# How to detect/trace if a Windows Live/PE used on a system?

Tags: windows, forensics

Is it possible to detect/trace if a Windows Live/PE is used on a system?
Like with logs or dumps etc.

Comment: From normal Windows logs? No.

Comment: @schroeder What about other ways?

Comment: Sure, there are all kinds of endpoint software that could log when a file is opened.

Comment: But it's unlikely that any such software would be running in the PE environment, even if it is present on the installed Windows environment.